# Configuration of Parallel running at Class level in TestNG

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I am trying to find out how to run all my TestNG tests in one class first, then all in the second class second and so forth.  I need to use parallel running to speed execution though. These are selenium tests so can be slow running.

Given the following TestNG suite file:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">

<test name="parallel-running-test">

    <classes>
        <class name="com.mycompany.myproject.mypackage.MyFirstClassTest"/>
        <class name="com.mycompany.myproject.mypackage.MySecondClassTest"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

..and the following 2 classes:

Class one:

```
public class MyFirstClassTest {

@Test
public void myFirstClassTestOne(){
    System.out.println("myFirstClassTestOne");
}

@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"myFirstClassTestOne"})
public void myFirstClassTestTwo(){
    System.out.println("myFirstClassTestTwo");
}

@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"myFirstClassTestTwo"})
public void myFirstClassTestThree(){
    System.out.println("myFirstClassTestThree");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"myFirstClassTestThree"})
public void myFirstClassTestFour(){
    System.out.println("myFirstClassTestFour");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"myFirstClassTestFour"})
public void myFirstClassTestFive(){
    System.out.println("myFirstClassTestFive");
   }
}
```

Class two:

```
public class MySecondClassTest {

@Test
public void mySecondClassTestOne(){
    System.out.println("mySecondClassTestOne");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"mySecondClassTestOne"})
public void mySecondClassTestTwo(){
    System.out.println("mySecondClassTestTwo");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"mySecondClassTestTwo"})
public void mySecondClassTestThree(){
    System.out.println("mySecondClassTestThree");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"mySecondClassTestThree"})
public void mySecondClassTestFour(){
    System.out.println("mySecondClassTestFour");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"mySecondClassTestFour"})
public void mySecondClassTestFive(){
    System.out.println("mySecondClassTestFive");
    }
}
```

Then the output is as follows:

[image]

...How can I have the report as:

```
MyFirstClassTest
   myfirstClassTestOne
   myfirstClassTestTwo
   myfirstClassTestThree
   myfirstClassTestFour
   myfirstClassTestFive

MySecondClassTest
   mySecondClassTestOne
   mySecondClassTestTwo
   mySecondClassTestThree
   mySecondClassTestFour
   mySecondClassTestFive
```

NB - I need dependsOnMethods and have obvs removed all the browser stuff and actual selenium stuff

Comment: How do you executing the code ?. I'd tried with your code its showing  report as you required .

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is just the way how IntelliJ is displaying the result of tests.
By default, it displays tests by the order they finish.

You can change it and sort them by alphabetical order if you prefer:

[image]

Sadly, IntelliJ is not grouping tests by class name (or I didn't find the way to do it).

Maybe you should ask for the feature on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Answer (score 0):

Steerpike, you can try running your **tests in parallel** (*instead of classes*) so slight changes to your XML should give you what you are after:

```
    !DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

    <test name="parallel-running-test1">        
        <classes>
            <class name="com.mycompany.myproject.mypackage.MyFirstClassTest"/>       
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="parallel-running-test2">        
        <classes>       
            <class name="com.mycompany.myproject.mypackage.MySecondClassTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Best of luck!